# How should I migrate Terraform data sources to resources?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

Using the AWS provider I have some S3 buckets that are used a few places in my .tf files as data sources. This has been working fine as I've brought more and more of my infra under Terraform control, and now I want to bring these buckets under Terraform control as actual resources, but I don't know the best sequence of steps. In AWS these buckets have replication rules, life cycle management rules, encryption rules, and so on, and I want to bring all of this into my .tf files.

In the past when I've imported new resources I've just done `terraform import` with a minimal resource block, then `terraform plan`, and the plan output has showed me all the discrepancies between my minimal resource block and my AWS reality. I then built up the resource block or added related resource blocks until my .tf files matched reality, and a final `terraform plan` confirmed that there were no changes needed. It seems, though, that there's something else needed when migrating data sources instead of just importing new resources.

I tried just changing my data blocks for these buckets into resource blocks, including changing all the references throughout my .tf files to refer to these as resources (i.e., without the "data." prefix in their name). Then I did `terraform import` of the buckets, confirmed they were in the state file, and finally `terraform state rm` of the data sources. Finally I did `terraform plan` and got "No changes. Your infrastructure matches the configuration."

This is not what I wanted. I wanted `terraform plan` to show me all the changes it was going to make to the buckets, since my minimal bucket resource blocks are missing tons of settings, like encryption, replication, life cycle, and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration#import), [s3_bucket_server_side_encryption_configuration](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket_server_side_encryption_configuration#import), and [s3_bucket_replication_configuration](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket_replication_configuration#import) are all separate configurations now, so they must be imported separately.

Also, to clarify, `terraform plan` is showing you all the changes it will make. That is because the replication configuration, for example, is a separate resource not yet controlled by your state, so no changes are to be made to it until you import your replication configuration.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks @theherk. I'm importing the separate related resources now, and it's working fine.